# Как на js определить браузер и запустить нужную функцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например если браузер гугл хром тогда показывать див блок с меню под номером один а если другой тогда показывать другой див блок с меню под номером два

```
if(Chrome==Chrome)

    alert('Меню 1');
else
    alert('Меню 2');
```

Comment: Гарантировано — никак. Браузер может выдавать совершенно произвольный UserAgent, имеет право. Не делайте очередной костыль. Вы должны детектировать не браузер, а наличие поддержки тех или иных фич.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению идеальных вариантов нет каждый скрипт имеет свои плюсы и минусы, советую посмотреть на этот скрипт [Определение браузера](http://yraaa.ru/publ/1/3-1-0-1544) он выводит имя браузера, а если по каким-то причинам подходит поищи в яндексе: *Определение браузера и его версии*

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19352753/5178153) одно из решений. Решения разные есть. Смотря что у вас на фронтенде находится.

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter

```
npm install webrtc-adapter // устанавливаете

import adapter from 'webrtc-adapter'; // импортируете

adapter.browserDetails.browser // определить браузер
```